# How to calculate the difference between max of today and max of previous day value in MONGODB

Tags: mongodb

```
{
metadata:{
dat:jkjcsvbdskjcbdskjcbdac,
meterId:kahcvajc
}
activeEnergy:1111,
actualtime:1689827191000
}
```

The document is something like that, I am facing problem only with activeEnergy so I want to focus on that only. Below I have written the code, in the first group object I have divided by year, month, day but in actual code it is dynamic, if the payload from frontend I receive is month and week then I group accordingly, but if I receive day in payload then I group by hour, I calculate the max and min energy of that hour and then sum for all hour, as activeEnergy is continuous, but the problem is that I am not getting data at every second so it is possible that I get the first data at 10:25am and last data at 10:45am therefore by taking max and min I only calculate for that 20 min and miss on all the remaining time data, ideally what I should do is max of this hour by max of previous hour. Similarly for the day the first document is at 12:59 AM and last Data at 11 pm, IF I calculate the max and min of the day I will still miss 2 hour data approx, so I have to find a way to find difference of max of today and max of previous day.
That becomes a problem because data is not grouped like that by me and I don't know any other way I can group data, how to solve the problem?

```
db.ts_events.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
        "y":{"$year": {$toDate: "$actualtime"}},
            "m":{"$month": {$toDate: "$actualtime"}},
            "d":{"$dayOfMonth": {$toDate: "$actualtime"}},
            "h":{"$hour": {$toDate: "$actualtime"}},
            "activeEnergy": 1,
            "metadata.meterId": 1,
            "activePower": 1,
            "actualtime": 1,
      
            "powerFactor": 1,
            "metadata.dat": 1
        }
    },



    {
        $match: {
            "metadata.dat": "62f0f3459731692a5eab5ad6/south0tpbit/tamilnadu5dvs8w/chennaidzc2yd/kknagarj4ffzo",
            "actualtime": {
                $gte: 1656613800000, $lte: 1659292199999,
            },
            //          "metadata.device":"ObjectId(62f0f9b5f757672222282d9)" how to check using object id?,
            "metadata.meterId": "911615402222257_2",
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                date: {
                    year: "$y",
                    month: "$m",
                    day: "$d",
//                    hour: "$h",
                },
                meter: "$metadata.meterId",
            },
            maxValue: {
                $max: "$activeEnergy"
            },
            minValue: {
                $min: "$activeEnergy"
            },
            averageActivePowerOfDay: { $avg: "$activePower" },
            averagePowerFactorOfDay: { $avg: "$powerFactor" },
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            differnce: {
                $subtract: [
                    "$maxValue",
                    "$minValue"
                ]
            },
        }
    },
    //
    //
    //
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null, res: {
                $push: '$$ROOT'
            }, differnceSum: {
                $sum: '$differnce'
            },
            averageActivePowerOverThePeriod: {
                $avg: "$averageActivePowerOfDay"
            },
            averagePowerFactorOverThePeriod: {
                $avg: "$averagePowerFactorOfDay"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [$setWindowFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/#std-label-setWindowFields-range)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { actualTime: { $toDate: "$actualtime" } } },
   {
      $setWindowFields: {
         partitionBy: "$metadata.dat",
         sortBy: { actualTime: 1 },
         output: {
            max_today: {
               $max: "$activeEnergy",
               window: { range: [-1, 1], unit: "day" }
            },
            max_yesterday: {
               $max: "$activeEnergy",
               window: { range: [-2, -1], unit: "day" }
            },
            day: {
               $last: "$actualTime",
               window: { range: [-1, 1], unit: "day" }
            },
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { metadata: "$metadata", day: "$day" },
         values: {
            $addToSet: {
               max_today: "$max_today",
               max_yesterday: "$max_yesterday"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $replaceWith: { $mergeObjects: ["$_id", { $first: "$values" }] } }
])
```